# Cypress - Failed to deserialize the V8 snapshot blob

Tags: cypress

When trying to run Cypress for the first time in Visual Studio code, I receive the following output:

```
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 6.4.0

  ×  Verifying Cypress can run C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\6.4.0\Cypress
    → Cypress Version: 6.4.0
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.

----------

#
Fatal error in , line 0
Failed to deserialize the V8 snapshot blob. This can mean that the snapshot blob file is corrupted or missing.
```

How can this issue be resolved so that Cypress will run and execute the tests for the application?

Comment: Almost similar issue happened during upgrade from 9.6.1 to 9.7.0 & given solution/accepted answers still resolves it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution that worked in my case in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5440)

The solution was to rename the Cypress cache and then reinstall Cypress from the application directory.

On Windows, the Cypress cache is in \AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache

```
npm install cypress
```

Comment: That helped. I had aborted a cypress test-run with CTRL-C, which must have messed it up.

Comment: The full path is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache

Comment: Why rename when you can delete :)

Answer (score 17):

You can also prune your cache since this is a know problem for many versions.

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress cache clear
```

Then run

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress install --force
```

This worked for me.

A note to Windows (10 in my case) users: to run the commands above you have to allow console scripts [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2) with `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process` issued at your terminal. The terminal must run with [admin privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/faq) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Lol for me I have run cypress from bad folder :)

`npm install cypress` works becouse it will create cypress